# How to add Margins on UITableView to inset content

Tags: ios, uitableview, margin

I have a table view and I want to include margins so that the table's content has some breathing room on the left and right, and also between cells.

[image]

Comment: You can't use margins to add space between cells. You need to add a subview (the white view in your image) that's inset from the cell's edges to make it appear that the cells are not abutting one another. See my answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26563497/ios-tableview-design-block-like-cells-with-margins-and-spacing/26565143#26565143

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do a table view like:

[image: TableView]

My Storyboard design is like:

[image: Storyboard]

What I did was I added a `UITableView` to the main view and gave a margin of 10. I added constraints as shown in figure. Changed the `Seperator style` to `None`.

Then I added two `UITableViewCell`s.

1. For Holding the data with custom row height 70.0
2. Row with same background of parentView with custom row height of 10.0

And implemented the methods like below:

```
// Row count (Twice as needed, for showing the insect)
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 15*2;
}

// Returns cell based on indexPath
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    // Decides whether content or inset
    if (indexPath.row%2)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ReuseInset"];
    }
    else
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ReuseMe"];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"MMP";
    }

    return cell;
}

// Returns custom row height based on indexpath
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    if (indexPath.row%2)
    {
        return 10.0;
    }
    return 70.0;
}
```