# Swift Add Margins To UITableVIew

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2

I [read the article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554006/how-to-add-margins-on-uitableview-to-inset-content) about add margins to UIViewTable, but the code is Object-C, and I want the example in Swift. I want create a UIViewTable like this:

[image]

Someone can help me?

Comment: In the table or in table cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the table view as you would normally use and just add a UIView in the tableView cell and apply constraints to it as i have attached in the image. And you can then add all your controls within the UIView , Also set the background colour of the tableview and table view cell to clear colour.

[image]

and you would get this output

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Then if you enable the cell's accessory like the disclosure indicator it would appear outside of the cell. This may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps as he mentioned into his answer and below is your swift code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 20
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell : UITableViewCell? = nil

    if indexPath.row % 2 == true {
        cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ReuseInset", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell!

    } else {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel!.text = "MMP"
        return cell
    }

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row % 2 == true {
        return 10
    }

    return 70
}
```